# Распаковка сжатой библиотеки в оперативную память?

Tags: javascript

Есть браузерное SPA приложение, оно использует библиотеку(шифрования пароля), для использования библиотека загружается на сторону клиента. Проблема в том что библиотека весит 5мб но zip библиотеки весит 600кб.  Как загружать на сторону клиента zip библиотеку и распаковывать её в оперативную память добавляя к содержимому SPA?

Comment: выбирайте: https://blog.bitsrc.io/10-javascript-compression-tools-and-libraries-for-2019-f141a0b15414

Comment: по ссылке содержатся минификаторы кода но не как не zip распаковка(

Comment: они и пакуют ваши скрипты для передачи на клиентский комп в минимальном виде, браузер же клиента сам распаковывает и использует скрипты. если нужно подгружать отдельный скрипт в определённом контроллере своего spa-приложения, то используйте requirejs

Comment: gzip и brotli встроены в браузер и не требуют никакой поддержки в js. Только сервер правильно настроить

Comment: Да, спасибо AlexeyTen, gzip  мне помогло.